# Send additional parameters to Stripe with Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

The Laravel docs states how to send extra parameters to Stripe like email. My question is how to send other parameters like adress and name.
Below is some of the customer.updated webhook.

```
"sources": {
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "card_1A3KXJUybOxa5viznC3iZy5U",
      "object": "card",
      "address_city": null, 
      "address_country": null,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line1_check": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "address_state": null,
      "address_zip": null,
```

And in my Laravel controller..

```
 $user->newSubscription('Silver', 'Silver')->create($creditCardToken, [
       'email' => $request->input('email'),
       'description' => 'Silver membership'
 ]);
```

The above works fine to send email and description to Stripe. But `'adress_city' => 'New York'` for example doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can send other data using **metadata** key like this below.

```
$user->newSubscription('Silver', 'Silver')->create($creditCardToken, [
   'email' => $request->input('email'),
   'description' => 'Silver membership',
   'metadata' => [
                'adress_city' => 'New York',
            ],

]);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, it is like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Extra = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Extra.Add("email", ByEmail);
StripeCustomer customer = customerService.List(new StripeCustomerListOptions() { Limit = 1, ExtraParams = Extra }).SingleOrDefault();
```